# Waiting for a DynamoDB table to be deleted from DB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I found this example in the DynamoDB [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelJavaTableOperationsExample.html) about synchronously deleting a given table.

Before calling this method, we sent the request to delete the table with the class `DeleteTableRequest`.

```
private static void waitForTableToBeDeleted(String tableName) {
        System.out.println("Waiting for " + tableName + " while status DELETING...");

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endTime = startTime + (10 * 60 * 1000);
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTime) {
            try {
                DescribeTableRequest request = new DescribeTableRequest().withTableName(tableName);
                TableDescription tableDescription = client.describeTable(request).getTable();
                String tableStatus = tableDescription.getTableStatus();
                System.out.println("  - current state: " + tableStatus);
                if (tableStatus.equals(TableStatus.ACTIVE.toString())) return;
            } catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Table " + tableName + " is not found. It was deleted.");
                return;
            }
            try {Thread.sleep(1000 * 20);} catch (Exception e) {}
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Table " + tableName + " was never deleted");
    }
```

My question is, how can they use in their latest example the `ResourceNotFoundException` when they mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/model/ResourceNotFoundException.html) that is deprecated? What should we use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation link you are pointing to is for V1 of the Amazon DynamoDB API, which is deprecated. The V2 version, which introduced local secondary indexes, is contained in the `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2` package. Here is the V2 [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/model/ResourceInUseException.html) for `ResourceNotFoundException`.